# How to record text modifications after calling recursive macro in Vim

Tags: vim, macros

I recorded in register `q` recursive macro that doubles every character in line: `^Vypl@q`, so it changes `abcde` to `aabbccddee`.

Now I want to wrap result with brackets with `A]^[I[^[` so result is `[aabbccddee]`. This macro is recorded in register `w`.

The problem is that when I record macro in register e with code `@q@w` only the first macro is processed. Seems like the end of recursion in @q breaks even the macro where it is executed. Is there a way to create the macro properly? Or is there a better way how to do the same? (I have several lines where it should be executed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the abort of the recursive macro cancels all pending commands, not just those from that macro. You can avoid that by submitting both macro executions via `:normal`:

```
:exe 'normal! @q' | normal! @w
```

Answer (score 2):

why you make so many nested macros?

why not just straightforwardly :

```
:s/./&&/g|s/^/[/|s/$/]
```

if you love macros, you can record the command above in register as macro.